# Is it possible to write this with a single replaceAll?

Tags: java, regex

This is the code I have thus far:

```
str = str.replace("PT", "X").replace("TP", "X").replace("T", "").replace("P", "");
```

Is it possible to write this shorter?

Comment: Is it intentional that your code returns "X" for "TPTP" and not "XX"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can write it in one, at least not with `String.replaceAll`.

You can write it in two, easily, e.g. `str = str.replaceAll("PT|TP", "X").replaceAll("T|P", "");`.

If you want to do it in a single pass, you could do it with `Matcher` like this (in Java 9+):

```
// Build these once, store in constants.
static final Map<String, String> REPLACEMENTS = Map.of("PT", "X", "TP", "X", "P", "", "T", "X");
static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("PT|TP|P|T");

// Then, when you want to do the replacement.
str = PATTERN.matcher(str).replaceAll(matchResult -> REPLACEMENTS.get(matchResult.group()));
```

Comment: Both your suggestions yield a different result than the original code for the string `TPTP`.

Comment: @Armali so they do. I guess it's up to OP as to whether the original or suggested version is correct; if it's the original, then no, you can't do it with a single replaceAll.